# Send datatable using SqlAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have DataSet method who receive sql string like:

```
 public DataSet GetDataSet(string sql, string TableName)
        {
            this._Errors = false;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql.ToString(), this.dbconn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                da.Fill(ds, TableName);
                return ds;
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                this.HandleSQLError(e, "GetDataSet", sql);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This works correctly, but now I want to send `DataTable` to receive as `Table Variable` in sql

with SqlCommand is simple like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sprocName, this.dbconn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(customerTypeTableName, SqlDbType.Structured));
    cmd.Parameters[customerTypeTableName].Value = customerTypeList;
```

How can I modify to do same with `SqlAdapter` method? Regards

Comment: Make cmd your adapter's select command.

Comment: Unrelated but _sql.ToString()_ makes no sense. _sql_ is already a string

Comment: The dataset has the property ds.AcceptChanges.  So the one command will take any changes an place back into the database.  The SQL command has for methods 1) Select 2) Delete 3) Insert 4) Update.  For the AcceptChanges to work you need all four commands.  So the Command builder will take a Select Command and create the other three.   See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @jdweng I think you missed the point if the question, OP wants to use a table as a parameter value. And AcceptChanges does not execute any commands.

Comment: If all you are going to do is fill a DataTable you dont need a local DataAdapter for that.  Nor do you need a DataSet for a single DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should write new function. There is no need to use DataAdapter. An object of type SqlCommand is quite enough as shown in the following snippet.

```
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpEmails", dt); // dt is your DataTable
// your UDDT type should exist on your SQL instance under UDDT types
    comm.Parameters[comm.Parameters.Count - 1].TypeName = "your UDDT type";
    comm.Parameters[comm.Parameters.Count - 1].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```